# Quilljs on enter not creating new line

Tags: javascript, quill

I am using Quilljs to create a simple rich text editor. But when I press enter, it does not create a new new line. I am using the following code to show and display the editor.
It displays just fine and I can type, but I can't create a new line.

```
<div id="master-editor"></div>

let quill = new Quill('#master-editor', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
            [{header: [1, 2, false]}],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
            ['image', 'formula', 'link'],
            [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}]
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code [here](https://quilljs.com/playground/) and it works fine, have you added something else, an event handler perhaps?

Comment: @Siddharth, I know I used the playground too, but somehow it does not work on my site. The only "handler" I have is `quill.root.innerHTML` to get the html, but I wouldn't call that a handler.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a mistake in the CSS.
I made a style (display: inline-block) that applied to all paragraphs, which in this case included all the `<p>`'s in the editor.